# callback external function declaration in node.js

Tags: node.js, callback

I'm doing a node.js workshop and learning about callbacks at the moment. I need to export a single function and use an asyncronic function to read a file. So far so good. Although I cannot undestand that last paragraph of the exercise (below) ¿What does it mean for something to be "ideomatic"? Also, I cannot undertand the usage of callback as parameter and then simply name "foo.." within the function. I'm guessing I'm missing something conceptually. Thanks in advance if you can help me understand.

*Also keep in mind that it is idiomatic to check for errors and do

  early-returns within callback functions:*

```
 function bar (callback) {  
   foo(function (err, data) {  
     if (err)  
       return callback(err) // early return  

     // ... no error, continue doing cool things with `data`  

     // all went well, call callback with `null` for the error argument  

     callback(null, data)  
   })  
 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this context "idiomatic" means, it is a "common and accepted practice" or an "appropriate practice".

*Also keep in mind that it is a common and accepted practice to check for errors and do early-returns within callback functions:*

---

An "idiom" in this context is a style of programming so when something is idiomatic, it is an appropriate style of programming.

---

One meaning of idiom from the [Collins dictionary](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/idiom) is this:

> **idiom**
>
> countable noun [usually singular]
>
> A particular idiom is a particular style of something such as music, dance, or architecture.

In this case, it would be a "style of programming".

---

The extension of this to "idiomatic" means it is a natural ways of doing things in this context.

---

I personally would not likely use "idomatic" in this context, but would rather says something like "common practice" or "accepted practice" or "recommended practice" or "accepted design pattern".

Comment: Understood. And yes, seems to be a kind of "good practice", not clear what value is added by calling it "ideomatic". Thanks for your reply!

Comment: Done! Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

After a few re-readings of the official documentation a few other docs I was able to complete the exercise. My solution below:

The main program *lsdmod.js*

```
var mi = require('./mod1.js');

mi(process.argv[2],process.argv[3], function(err,data) {
    if (err)
        return console.log('error:' + err);

for (var i of data){
    console.log(i);
}

});
```

The module *mod1.js*:

```
module.exports = function(ruta, ext, callback){
var fs = require('fs');
var path = require('path');
list = [];

fs.readdir(ruta, doneReading);

function doneReading(error, data) {
    if (error) {
        return callback(error);
    }

    for (i of data) {
        if (path.extname(i) == "."+ext) {
            list.push(i);
        }

    }
    return callback(null, list);
}

}`
```